# Find $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x_n}{x_1 + \cdots + x_n}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Suppose that $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a bounded sequence, and that $x_n>0$ holds for all positive integer $n$.

Find $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x_n}{x_1 + \cdots + x_n}$.

Comment: Any ideas, guesses, thoughts, work?

Comment: Is it series or sequence you meant?

Comment: @AnjanDebnath does it affect your understanding?

Comment: @JohnFernley Does my understanding affect your understanding? For the first time, when I saw the question it was " Suppose that $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a bounded 'series' and now after the editing is done(after you made the comment), I see "bounded sequence". Do I need to elaborate more for understanding?

Comment: @AnjanDebnath If you understand the question don't distract from it with this pedantry. We weren't talking about my understanding.

Comment: @JohnFernley Same here as I believe I have the right to make clear my doubt.

Comment: @AnjanDebnath If it does affect your understanding a simple "yes" would have done for your first answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Hint:** It is useful to separately consider the cases $\sum x_n < \infty$ and $\sum x_n = \infty$.  In the latter case, remember that $\{x_n\}$ is bounded.

Comment: Do you know that the limit exists ?

Comment: @Rene Do you mean the sum? The partial sums are monotonic increasing, so either they are unbounded and diverge to $+\infty$ or are bounded and hence have a limit.

Comment: Sorry, you are right about that, but if the series diverges, I dont see that the limit exists or is even uniquely determined.

Comment: @Rene When a numerator is bounded and the denominator monotonically increases without bound, of course the ratio's limit exists!

Answer (score 2):

I think the limit is zero. The above hint is useful. For $\sum x_n<\infty$, $x_n\rightarrow 0$ ($n\rightarrow \infty$). In the case $\sum x_n=\infty$, the answer is obvious.

Comment: Boundedness of the sequence is required in the second part, I won't hear "obvious".